# How do I use multiple programming languages in Docker?

Tags: python, node.js, docker

My project, written in Node.js, runs a Python file that needs to be built. Previously, I have used a script to set up the project when pulled from GitHub. I'd like to use Docker instead but am having issues when running multiple FROMs. My understanding is that FROM creates a new image and it is for this reason that my project build fails. What is the solution to this?

**Original Shell Script**

```
yarn
git clone https://github.com/<directory>
mv <directory> <new_name>
cd <directory>
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

**Attempted Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/<directory>
RUN mv /usr/src/app/<directory> /usr/src/app/<new_name>

RUN pip3 install -r <new_name>/requirements.txt

FROM node:11

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --production

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

Comment: You can not combine two images like that. You have some options: 1. install Python into the node image. 2. install node in the Python image 3. install both into a base image like Debian or Alpine.

Comment: I'd like to add to @KlausD. list 4. google 'docker python and node' and see if there are already any images doing what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use any one image and install other application into that image. So your dockerfile may look like:

```
FROM node:11

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/<directory>
RUN mv /usr/src/app/<directory> /usr/src/app/<new_name>

RUN Command to install python 3.6 and pip3

RUN pip3 install -r <new_name>/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --production

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

You can refer this [sample dockefile](https://github.com/dockerfile/python/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: Ended up using `FROM python:3.6` and then installing node. Success, thank you!